# Is there an askubuntu button I can put on my site?

Tags: feature-request, badges, site-promotion, flair

I have seen the flair boxes which look kinda funky, but what if I want just a little badge to go along with other ones like you see on the left of http://podcast.ubuntu-uk.org/ ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a smaller alternative similar to the follow us & Subscribe badges

[image: Small Ask ubuntu badge]

You can get the SVG original from my [deviantart](http://blood-angel79.deviantart.com/art/Buttons-For-Ask-ubuntu-200516962) page

Comment: No problem I should be doing more of this stuff but you know never enough hours in the day.

Answer (score 8):

There aren't any official ones.

In case they're any use, I made these for you:

[image]

[image]

You probably want to change it, so here's the [SVG Version](http://hour45.com/files/4d7941a7a0f06.svg) of it.

Comment: groovy.  very nice.

Comment: **Very** nice looking.